# I can send Google Assistant messages to my windows application, but how do I send a message back?

Tags: windows, automation, google-assistant-sdk, ifttt

I'm using IFTTT to send a Google Assistant message to my Windows application via Drop Box. If I say "[keyword] [message]" (for example: "Computer: Play Game of Thrones Season 2 Episode 4") IFTTT will write the text translation of [message] to a file on drop box that my application monitors and from there I can read the [message] and act on it.

What I would like to be able to do is send a reply back to the device that sent the message... For example if I tell my phone to have my computer start a movie on my computer and for whatever reason my app can't find the movie I want to be able to communicate that back to the device that originally sent the message, whether that be my cell phone or tablet or Google Home smart speaker.

I know there is probably no official way to do this but i'm looking for creative solutions (like the one I use to get the message in the first place)... anything at all that works even if it involves multiple third-party services.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way to send back an acknowledgement through the IFTTT integration. You'd need to build your own [Action](https://actions.google.com) which would use something like push notifications to communicate between your local device and a cloud-based webhook.